# Problem with RequiredPlayerRange on spawners

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is on the latest Minecraft version, 1.16.4

I have been trying to figure out how to get it to work with NBTExplorer. I changed the RequiredPlayerRange to higher then default amount which was 16 now its 40, yet whenever I save it and just restart my game to see if the changes applied it still defaults back to its original range yet still says 40 in the NBTExplorer.

went to ahead and checked on the official wiki of Minecraft to find I had to change MaxNearbyEntities as well, though I'm unsure what to do so I changed it to the same value, still nothing

update during writing!

found a command that might work?

```
/data merge block -1537 39 771 {RequiredPlayerRange: 30}
```

standing above the spawner and counted 1 block off the Y coordinate

^ this gave me an error: that position is not loaded

Though, I have no idea what that could mean really.

Could someone explain why I am getting this?

Also, if you know of a different fix for the problem, please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this whilst standing on top of the spawner:

```
/data merge block ~ ~-1 ~ {RequiredPlayerRange: 30}
```